# Python, add strings to dictionary with loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What I mean, is that the dictionary would fill up in this way: 
`{f"{username}": {"Username": username, "Password": password}}`

 *(which should look like that:)*
`{"test1": {"Username": "test1", "Password": "test-password"}}`

*(...in this way,)* so you can access the sub-dict over the username (`f"{username}`), and then in the sub-dict, it shows you the username and the password. 
If I have for example a few usernames, I want to create new values in the main-dict, where the sub-dict gets added. (For example, you put the username and password into the sub-dict and after you have added that to the main-dict, you clear with with `{dict}.clear()`

All that should be possible to make in either a loop (doesn't matter if its `while` or `for i in range()`

I have tried to achieve that, with following code:

```
maindict = {}
subdict = {}

while True:
    username = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")

    subdict["username"] = username
    subdict["password"] = password
    maindict[username] = subdict
    print(maindict)
```

but my problem with that one is, if you run it once, it returns the right thing. But after the second time, the first value of the sub-dict gets overwritten with the second input and it creates a new the new value in the main-dict (which is correct, but it shouldn't overwrite the values of the sub-dict in the first value of the main-dict)
If you can't follow me there anymore, it prints out this:

```
Enter username: test1
Enter password: test1
{'test1': {'username': 'test1', 'password': 'test1'}}

Enter username: test2
Enter password: test2
{'test1': {'username': 'test2', 'password': 'test2'}, 'test2': {'username': 'test2', 'password': 'test2'}}
```

So as you see, it overwrites the "test1" values (of the sub-dict) and creates a second value in the main-dict.

 
Sorry if its confusing, I just couldn't find a solution for that. If I have explained it badly, just post a comment and ill give my best to explain it further. 

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are having this issue because you have `subdict = {}` outside of the while loop. So, each time you update value of `username` and `password` you are updating the same dictionary `subdict`, instead of creating a new dictionary for each user. So, you should keep the line `subdict = {}` inside your while loop, which will create a new dictionary for each user.

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks! I dont know how I didn't thought about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that in the line `maindict[username] = subdict`, the value for all the keys is referring to same variable `subdict`, hence the repetition when you run it the second time.

To fix this, you can just replace the line with `maindict[username] = subdict.copy()`, which will ensure that the previous entries don't get overridden. This may not be the most performant solution, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the empty `subdict` inside the loop, otherwise it always points to the same object in memory and the value are overwritten:

```
maindict = {}

while True:

    subdict = {}
    username = input("Enter username: ")
...
```